# In function int main(): class name was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++, c++11

Im using vscode and im new to c++. I learned how to create a header file link to its cpp and use it to main.cpp.  The only problem bugs me out is why it causes an error this is my simple code.

Name.h

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
class myname
{
public:
    void setname(std::string name);
    void prname();
private:
    std::string Name;
};
```

Name.cpp

```
#include "Name.h"

void myname::setname(std::string name)
{
    Name = name;
}
void myname::prname()
{
    std::cout<<"Hello :"<<Name<<std::endl;
}
```

Maiin.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "Name.h"
using std::cout;
using std::string;
using std::endl;

int main()
{
    myname Epoy;  // IN FUNCTION INT MAIN: ERROR myname was not declared in this scope 
    Epoy.setname("Jomar"); //note myname <-rename "BUT THIS IS NOT THE ERROR CAUSE THIS JUST HAPPEN BECAUSE OF THE ERROR ABOVE " 
    Epoy.prname();
    return 0;
}
```

also i tried so many method i even compiled this by using g++ Maiin.cpp Name.cpp - o Maiin
Still didnt work

Comment: The code you posted is correct,. Check that you saved all your files and you are actually compiling the right files you think you are compiling

Comment: Uhmmm g++ Maiin.cpp Name.cpp - o Maiin is this the way you compile with header? Cause i did this already and still throw some error

Comment: Try using `cat` or otherwise to view the content of those files and check it is exactly as shown in the question. The error would occur if Name.h  had different content for example. And if you edit Name.h to contain nonsense and rerun the same command, you should get different build errors etc.

Comment: The problem is that the files you are compiling are not the same as the files you have posted in the question

Comment: Also i use code runner so if i hit the run button. It shown on the terminal g++ Maiin.cpp - o Maiin So does it means it didnt compile with the Name.cpp?. Because evertime i run thats the only thing shown in the terminal

Comment: Yes that means it didn't compile Name.cpp but that would not produce the error you are seeing. Try using the commandline instead, and check the content of the files via the commandline

Answer (score -1):

Edit: Community want me to add more details.

What I asked was, have you write **header guards** in your header file:  `#ifndef Name_H`, `#define Name_H`, `#endif` ? Since you use vscode you have to done it manually.

Like this:

```
#ifndef Name_H  
#define Name_H  

#include <iostream>  
#include <string>  
class myname  
{  
  public:  
    void setname(std::string name);  
    void prname();  
  private:  
    std::string Name;  
};  

#endif
```

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.